# MySQL Inner Join / Max Value / Group

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies if this has already been covered but I have checked many other questions and can't seem to get the result I want.

SQL Fiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0a1f

I would want to return the highest level achievements grouped by the category. So the dummy data it would return the rows with 'Newbie Leveller' and 'Amateur Banker'

```
SELECT 
    achievementid, 
    a.title,
    a.level
FROM 
    player_achievements p
    INNER JOIN achievements a ON p.achievementid = a.id
```

I did try and change the tables abit (added category & level to the player_achievements, felt like this was wrong as the data is in the other table) and used this query:

```
SELECT 
    achievementid, 
    a.title 
FROM 
    player_achievements p1 
    INNER JOIN achievements a ON p1.achievementid = a.id 
WHERE 
    p1.level =(
        SELECT 
        MAX(p2.level) 
    FROM 
        player_achievements p2 
    WHERE 
        p1.category = p2.category
) 
AND playerid = 44
```

But it only returned one row

Comment: Your question and data simply make no sense.  What does "player" have to do with the question?  Why does the data have achievement ids that are not in the achievements table?

Comment: For the second code set you have given, when you use equal (=) operator for a sub query it will only return a single value. What you have to do is write 'IN' instead of equals. Write: "WHERE p1.level IN (SELECT..."
Where you have written it as "WHERE p1.level=(SELECT.."

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've changed the link now.

Comment: @Oshan_Mendis I've tried with IN instead of = and it still only returns 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add `achievements` into the subquery like this

```
SELECT 
    achievementid, 
    title 
FROM player_achievements pa1 
INNER JOIN achievements a1 ON pa1.achievementid = a1.id 
WHERE 
    a1.level =(
        SELECT MAX(a2.level) 
        FROM player_achievements pa2 
        INNER JOIN achievements a2 ON pa2.achievementid = a2.id 
        WHERE a1.category = a2.category and 
              pa2.playerid = pa1.playerid
    ) 
AND pa1.playerid = 44
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4f0c7725d342b0ab222b98d2cb7861ee)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM achievements JOIN (
    SELECT category, max(level) level
    FROM player_achievements JOIN achievements ON achievementid = id 
    WHERE playerid = 44
    GROUP BY category
) t USING (category, level);
```

Comment: I've tried this and it gives the wrong data.  Shows max_level of 2 for 'Banker' but shows Standard Banker instead of Average Banker and same for the level one